# how I can save 2 value(text & value of that text) to a jtree node

Tags: java, jtree, treenode

I create a Jtree in java, I would like to add 2 value to each node , *I mean is it possible we have 2 value in each node? **for example in JCombobox we can assign one value as text and the other value is text value.***

```
combobox item1 =  text1 + value1

combobox item2 =  text2 + value2

combobox item3 =  text3 + value3
```

So is there any thing like this for Jtree nodes?
if not what is your suggestion for store some thing like this?

because I want to save this data in database and also retrieve form database, it will help me so much to create my node path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find an example in the [Swing Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tree.html). There a custom object (of class `BookInfo` in that case) is attached to each node in the tree. You may do the same with any other object.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Howard's answer:

Your object can implement a `Serializable` interface, so you can store it in the database as is. Or, you may store all of object fields in different columns (preferred way). To work with databse, take a look on `JDBC` and, as an advice for future, at `Hibernate`.

Comment: I always heard about Hibernate but I dont know I should start from where? would you provide necessary information about Hibernate maybe it's question of so many person, I use Jdeveloper for my developing. Do I need download any package for Hibernate? how please explane

Comment: Hibernate is a library, that allows you work with objects stored in database like with normal Java objects (such approach called ORM). Hibernate have a nice learning curve, so it's not so hard to start. You may download hibernate from the [official site](http://www.hibernate.org/). It also have a nice manual, available in several languages, supplied with Hibernate itself is a `documentation\manual` folder. It has about 400 pages, but don't be scared, you may get start after first 3 chapters. They also have online documentation.

Comment: Thanks I will go throw this one I hope it help me so much... thanks for your informations